# how to print dictionary values in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries of which i want to print certain keys from each dictionary:

```
dict_results=[{'terms':['hi','bye'],'title':'01234def','text':'hello, how are you?'},{'terms':...}...]
```

This doesnt work:

```
for item in dict_results:
    print "{0},{1}".format(item[0]['title'],item[0]['text'])
```

## key error: 0

Comment: Remove `[0]`, `item` is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict_results=[{'terms':['hi','bye'],'title':'01234def','text':'hello, how are you?'}]

for item in dict_results:

    print("{} {} {}".format(item['terms'], item['title'],item['text']))

    ['hi', 'bye'] 01234def hello, how are you?
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the `list`, then access each dictionary's keys:

```
>>> dict_results=[{'terms':['hi','bye'],'title':'01234def','text':'hello, how are you?'},
...               {'terms':0, 'title':'hello', 'text':'world'}]
>>> for d in dict_results:
...     print(d['title'], d['text'])
...
01234def hello, how are you?
hello world
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but i have to go with the other one as it was how i structured my question.